# Middleman blog.permalink error

Tags: ruby, sinatra, middleman

I'm having a problem with middleman's permalink option.

When I have *blog.permalink = ":year-:month-:day-:title"* in the config.rb file, the output is mysite.com/2014-01-16-HelloWorld/ and file can not be found. For some reason it ignores *blog.prefix = "blog"*.

When it is like *blog.permalink = "{year}-{month}-{day}-{title}"*, it links to post but the url is *mysite.com/blog/%7Byear%7D-%7Bmonth%7D-%7Bday%7D-%7Btitle%7D/*.

Here is what's in the blog section of the config.rb:

```
activate :blog do |blog|  
   blog.prefix = "blog"  
   blog.permalink = ":year-:month-day-:title"  
   blog.layout = "blog/_post"  
   blog.default_extension = ".markdown"  
   blog.summary_separator = /SPLIT_SUMMARY_BEFORE_THIS/  
end
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Which version of Middleman are you using?

Comment: Could you post the config.rb code from the `activate :blog do ...end` block?

Comment: @karlfreeman I'm using "middleman", "~>3.2.0"

Comment: @acsmith the code is below:  
  
activate :blog do |blog|<br>
  blog.prefix = "blog"  
  blog.permalink = "{}:year-:month-day-:title"  
  blog.layout = "blog/_post"  
  blog.default_extension = ".markdown"  
  blog.summary_separator = /SPLIT_SUMMARY_BEFORE_THIS/  
end

Comment: It's really better to edit your question with the code in it…it's tough to read within the comment because the comment removes line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `blog.permalink = ":year-:month-:day:title.html"` (or remove the .html if you are using directory indexes).